# Register CSR via Client object

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, client-side-rendering

Im trying to register a client side rendering script to a webpart using JS to do so. Im having a hard time finding examples on how to do this, is anyone able to help me out? Below is what i got allready, where im fetching the webpart manager, really all i need is a pointer to as if how to find the right webpart in the Collection, and register the JavaScript file on it.

```
    this.getWebPartManager = function (list) {
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oFile = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);

    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    this.collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

    ctx.load(collWebPart);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.addCSRScriptToWebPart), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onError));


}

this.addCSRScriptToWebPart = function(){



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to set `JSLink` property using JSOM:

```
function setupJsLink(pageUrl, wpId,jsLinkUrl,success,error)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var page = context.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
    var wpm = page.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var webpartDef = wpm.get_webParts().getById(new SP.Guid(wpId));
    var webpart = webpartDef.get_webPart();
    var properties = webpart.get_properties();
    properties.set_item("JSLink", jsLinkUrl);
    webpartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
          success();                  
        }, 
        error);
}
```

Usage

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {

    var pageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
    var webPartId = 'f6989c4d-1387-4657-a8f6-30dc0a4f967f';   //web part id
    var jsLinkUrl = '~sitecollection/Style Library/tasks.js';  //jslink url
    setupJsLink(pageUrl, webPartId,jsLinkUrl,
       function(){
          console.log('Saved.');
       },
       function(sender, args) {
          console.log(args.get_message());
       });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From here: [Update/set web part property JSLink using JavaScript CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218732/update-set-web-part-property-jslink-using-javascript-csom/218733#218733)

```
UpdateWebPartProperty();

function UpdateWebPartProperty()
{
    var listName = "list1";
    var jslinkURL = "~sitecollection/SiteAssets/testjslink.js";
    var pageUrl = "/Lists/" + listName + "/NewForm.aspx";

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    console.log(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + pageUrl); 
    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

    clientContext.load(collWebPart);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () 
    {
        var webPartDef = null;
        for (var x = 0; x < collWebPart.get_count() && !webPartDef; x++) {
            var temp = collWebPart.get_item(x);
            console.log(temp.get_id().toString());
        }
        webPartDef = collWebPart.get_item(0);
        if (!webPartDef) {
            console.log("Web Part: " + wpId + " not found on page: " + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
            return;
        }
        var webPartProperties = webPartDef.get_webPart().get_properties();
        clientContext.load(webPartProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                var webpartprops = webPartProperties;
                console.log(webpartprops.get_item('JSLink'));
                webpartprops.set_item("JSLink", jslinkURL);
                webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
                clientContext.load(webPartDef);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    console.log("Web part properties saved.");
                },
                function() 
                {
                    console.log("Failed save Web part Properties"); 
                });
            }, 
            function () 
            { 
                console.log("Failed to load web part properties"); 
            });
    }, 
    function () { 
        console.log("Failed to load web part collection"); 
    });
}
```