# Update/set web part property JSLink using JavaScript JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

How to update/set web part properties for example **JSLink** using CSOM JavaScript.

Comment: why are you asking and then answering your own question ?

Comment: @Gautam so that it is useful for others :)
https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UpdateWebPartProperty();

function UpdateWebPartProperty()
{
    var listName = "list1";
    var jslinkURL = "~sitecollection/SiteAssets/testjslink.js";
    var pageUrl = "/Lists/" + listName + "/NewForm.aspx";

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    console.log(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + pageUrl); 
    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

    clientContext.load(collWebPart);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () 
    {
        var webPartDef = null;
        for (var x = 0; x < collWebPart.get_count() && !webPartDef; x++) {
            var temp = collWebPart.get_item(x);
            console.log(temp.get_id().toString());
        }
        webPartDef = collWebPart.get_item(0);
        if (!webPartDef) {
            console.log("Web Part: " + wpId + " not found on page: " + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
            return;
        }
        var webPartProperties = webPartDef.get_webPart().get_properties();
        clientContext.load(webPartProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                var webpartprops = webPartProperties;
                console.log(webpartprops.get_item('JSLink'));
                webpartprops.set_item("JSLink", jslinkURL);
                webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
                clientContext.load(webPartDef);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    console.log("Web part properties saved.");
                },
                function() 
                {
                    console.log("Failed save Web part Properties"); 
                });
            }, 
            function () 
            { 
                console.log("Failed to load web part properties"); 
            });
    }, 
    function () { 
        console.log("Failed to load web part collection"); 
    });
}
```